# Using ModelBuilder to Create Python Script for xls to csv Conversion?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, excel, error-000732, error-000735

I am currently trying to create a python script within ModelBuilder to convert an xls file to csv.

I created one already using the "Table to CSV" tool which was successful. However, I tried to add data to the xls file and run the script again and it choked on the "csv already exists". I tried adding  "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" to overwrite the csv already existing, but it still choked when I tried to run it again. (Script and error code below)

Script:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:/Temp/Excel_and_CSV_Conversion_Tools/ExcelTools/Excel and CSV Conversion Tools.tbx")


# Local variables:
Sheet1_ = "R:\\Workspace\\Es\\Employee\\Maggie\\OptOut\\Test.xlsx\\Sheet1$"
test_csv = "R:\\Workspace\\Es\\Employee\\Maggie\\OptOut\\test.csv"

# Process: TableToCSV
arcpy.TableToCSV_tableconversion(Sheet1_, test_csv, "COMMA")
```

Error:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Table Name: Dataset R:\Workspace\Es\Employee\Maggie\OptOut\Test.xlsx\Sheet1$ does not exist or is not supported
ERROR 000725: Output CSV: Dataset R:\Workspace\Es\Employee\Maggie\OptOut\test.csv already exists.
Failed to execute (TableToCSV).
```

My ultimate goal is to create a script I can set up in task scheduler to run on it's own everyday to convert an xls to csv, without using a script that requires macros to be enabled in the xls.

I am at the beginner beginner level when it comes to python script.

Comment: I guess you are unaware of the ESRI code sharing website? Why bother writing all this code when the tools already exists [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f3d91b8f852042e289e09a7ec8342431)?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the arcpy environment property to true in the beginning of the script

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```